# Azure AD SSO not getting redirected after logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement azure AD login in a reactjs based SPA application with the help of [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react) package. I was able to do login properly, but when I try to logout I am getting stuck at this page. It won't redirect me back to my login page after a successful logout.

[image: issue]

I have added the following for redirection in msalConfig

```
redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/",
postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/"
```

I also tried setting Front-channel logout URL in azure portal but none seems to work. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XIiQZL7pERQ) of the issue that I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try keeping those values like below:

```
postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
redirectUri: window.location.origin,
```

Check out [Connect Your React App with Azure AD using react-aad-msal.](https://medium.com/@pavelray/connect-your-react-app-with-azure-ad-using-3ddd39223d27) for detailed tutorial about this.